# Taking mouse control in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I watnt o create a tutorial/guide inside in my application, creating a "demonstration". For this purpose, I need to capture the mouse of the computer, and to be able to move it and click with it.

I want it to feel like if somebody else were there controling your computer. This will be completed with a video of someone, to make you feel like this someone is doing it live in that moment.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a video as a tutorial?

Comment: @Gino I want it to be in the desktop of the client, as real as possible.

Comment: You could instead use a video wich fills the whole screen and prevent the focus out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't WPF solution. You have to use P/Invoke.

To disable keyboard/mouse use [`BlockInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API (as far as I understand, you don't want user to break up your "demo").
To simulate user input, use [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.
`SendInput` at pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput

Another option is to use third-party simulators, like [this](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).